# Rails - using increment! with user input

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to assign a score for student users in my Rails app. They have a param called :points. I want to update the number of points they have based on teacher user input - they can give them 1 point, 2 points, 5 points, etc. I am using increment! but I can only choose 1 value to give them. I wrote an if statement that isn't working. This code works:

```
    <%= form_for student do |f| %>
      <%= f.submit "+ 1" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= form_for student do |g| %>
      <%= g.submit "+ 2" %>
    <% end %>
```

and controller:

```
  def update
     @student = Student.find(params[:id])
       @student.increment!(:points, 1)
       redirect_to '/pages/points'
 end
```

but it can only increase by 1 point (both buttons increase by 1). So I wrote this if statement and included hidden fields to update the :amount param:

```
       <%= form_for student do |f| %>
       <%= f.hidden_field :amount, :value => 1 %>
        <%= f.submit "+ 1" %>
       <% end %>
       <%= form_for student do |g| %>
       <%= g.hidden_field :amount, :value => 2 %>
         <%= g.submit "+ 2" %>
       <% end %>
```

and controller:

```
   def update
     @student = Student.find(params[:id])
     if :amount == 1
       @student.increment!(:points, 1)
       redirect_to '/pages/points'
     elsif :amount == 2
       @student.increment!(:points, 2)
       redirect_to '/pages/points'
     else
       @student.increment!(:points, 3)
       redirect_to '/pages/points'
     end
   end
```

and this returns 3 points each time, which means :amount is not updating in the hidden field. Am I going about this the wrong way? Is there a better way to use increment! to change the point values, or is there a different way to update :amount so my if statement will work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this by having one form and checking which submit button was pressed.

```
<%= form_for student do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "+ 1" %>
  <%= f.submit "+ 2" %>
<% end %>
```

then just check the `params[:commit]`

```
   def update
     @student = Student.find(params[:id])
     case params[:commit]
     when '+ 1'
       @student.increment!(:points, 1)
     when '+ 2'
       @student.increment!(:points, 2)
     else
       @student.increment!(:points, 3)
     end       
     redirect_to '/pages/points'
   end
```

This line makes NO sense in Ruby...

```
if :amount == 1
```

`:amount` is a symbol, `1` is an integer.  They can never be equal.  It's like saying

```
if "cat" == 7
```

Symbols never in themselves hold values, they aren't variables.  They can be used as the key to a variable stored in a hash.

```
my_hash = {amount: 5, colour: 'blue'}

my_hash[:amount] == 5
=> true
```

Rails `params`, although not exactly hashes, are hash-like structures with key/value pairs.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for explaining it to me. When I use this code, though, both buttons still update by 3 points.

Comment: so `params[:submit]` is probably missing (and returns nil).  Add the gem `pry` to your gemfile for development, and do a `bundle install` and then add the line `binding.pry` immediately after `def update` run the rails server, try one of the buttons, and then when your rails server halts you can type in `params` on the server to see what's in `params`.  See if you have the `params[:submit]` and what it contains.

Comment: That gem is great, thank you for the suggestion. It looks like it's coming through under [:commit] rather than [:submit]. I changed it over and it's now working! I can even add more point values and they work as well. Thank you so much! I really appreciate the help and explanations.

Comment: Duh!  Yes, it's `commit` not `submit`, sorry.  Edited the answer.  Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work, because of `if :amount == 1`(
You should do `if params[:amount] == 1`).
And probably, try something like

```
   def update
     @student = Student.find(params[:id])
     @student.increment!(:points, params[:amount])
     redirect_to '/pages/points'
   end
```

Form fields like this will provide sending params[:amount] with selected value

```
<%= form_for student do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit '+1', name: 'amount', value: 1 %>
  <%= f.submit '+2', name: 'amount', value: 2 %>
  <%= f.submit '+3', name: 'amount', value: 3 %>
<%= end %>
```

Comment: If I try to do it without the if statement (like what you posted), I get the error: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum. Changing to params[:amount] still returned 3 rather than 1 or 2.

Comment: Try to change `<%= form_for student do |f| %>` to `<%= form_for :student do |f| %>`

Comment: The hidden_field has a name (and therefore a reference in `params`) that includes the object class.  You should actually be checking for `params[:student][:amount]`not `params[:amount]`.  Use a gem like `pry` to inspect the params inside the update method.

Comment: I returned to previous variant due to error, described by author (`nil can't be coerced into Fixnum`) Thiis could only be happened if `@student = Student.find(params[:id])` didnt raise exception

Comment: `params[:id]` is correct and didn't need to change.  but the amount is `params[:student][:amount]`   The `nil can't be coerced...` is caused by the fact that `params[:amount]` doesn't exist.  Effectivly the line becomes `@student.increment!(:points, nil)` which creats the error.

Comment: As I added `<%= f.submit '+3', name: 'amount', value: 3 %>`, `params[:amount]` is working like a charm as well without ifelses in controller)